# Windows phone KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync is throwing System.NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop a music player app for windows phone.

I am getting the following exception while trying to access music library

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
>   implemented. at Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get Music Library()

I am trying to access music library using the below code

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> albums = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByArtist);
```

I have searched regarding this exception, but went in vain.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you allowed accessing it in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

This method works fine in apps that use Windows Runtime. You are using Silverlight, so you can't run it. Windows Phone Silverlight apps don't have direct access to files. You have two options to fix this:

1) Start a new project that uses Windows Runtime instead of Silverlight.

2) Use different method that works in Windows Phone Silverlight:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
AlbumCollection albums = library.Albums;
```